# How to proxy Apache Kafka producer requests on the Kafka broker, and redirect to a separate Kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

How to proxy Apache Kafka producer requests on the Kafka broker, and redirect to a separate Kafka cluster?

In my specific case, it's not possible to update the clients that write to this cluster. This means, it's not feasible to do the following:

1. Updating the bootstrap broker configuration in the client
2. Rewrite the client code to support [Confluent REST Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/index.html)

Therefore, I'm looking for proxy that would work on the [Kafka Protocol](http://kafka.apache.org/protocol.html)

Here are some potential options I've discovered so far:

1. [Kafka-proxy](https://github.com/grepplabs/kafka-proxy)
2. [EnvoyProxy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/)

Does anyone have any experience with the tools above (or alternative tools) that would allow me to redirect a binary TCP Kafka request to a separate Kafka cluster?

Comment: Why not MirrorMaker? The problem with a proxy is that destination cluster might not have same topics or same partitions for matching topics

Comment: The use case is that we need to perform maintenance on the Kafka cluster (e.g. expand capacity) and if the cluster is under a lot of load already the maintenance can actually cause an outage itself (i.e. rebalancing data). So if could redirect client producers to a separate Kafka cluster, this would reduce load prior to expanding capacity. Unfortunately MirrorMaker does not help that problem.

Comment: So, how will you consolidate the data back together after expanding capacity?

Comment: If you're using a hub and spoke architecture, you could mirror the traffic from the temporary "spoke/source" Kafka cluster back to an "hub/aggregate" Kafka cluster. For the maintenance use case above, it will only work on the "spoke/source" Kafka clusters.

Answer (score 1):

Since late 2021, Envoy proxy does that for Produce requests (with [kafka-mesh-filter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.22.0/configuration/listeners/network_filters/kafka_mesh_filter)), however it's still a work in progress.

In general your Proxy will need to understand the Kafka protocol and maintain necessary connections to upstream Kafka cluster(s).